# Why is wordpress widget cutting off part of the site in mobile view?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, mobile

The site is [HERE](http://jadeluxurycondos.com/jadeluxurycondos-new/) On the home page there is a widget titled Featured Listings.  The widget looks great in the desktop view.  The same page in mobile view is cutting the right side of the widget off.  This widget is the only thing in mobile view that is causing conflict while all other parts of the page look correct.

I am a novice with WP and need some insight to solve this problem.

Comment: This is not a WP issue -- more like a CSS issue.

Comment: Also the title is unclear -- it says "a widget is cutting off part of the site view", which might imply the fact that the widget is affecting the entire site when in fact the issue is self-contained within the widget (both visually as well as in terms of code).

Comment: @MihaiStancu It is on WP framework so it is tagged as such.  And your 2nd comment is pretty vague, would u please elaborate in details what u mean?

Comment: The question title also contains "wordpress widget", which implies the problem would relate to a "wordpress widget" but it (most likely) is a CSS problem which has little or nothing to do with the wordpress widget in particular and more to do with your other CSS elements in the site.

Comment: If a server is misconfigured you can't say it's an "Apache module" problem, even if the problem occurs while running the module. It may be that you're using something in a way it was never intended to be used or combining things that were not designed to work together.

Comment: So I'm just being nit-picky about your choice of words when describing your problem -- because a better choice of words can help you find better quality resources (ex.: when googling) or it can help you make yourself understood in regards to peers (such as us) when asking a question.

Comment: Tech jargon may sound like just another awfully pompous way to say things you can say in plain speech -- but it's not, it's the same as useful as [punctuation](http://www.cannylinguist.co.uk/2011/11/punctuation-saves-lives.html). If I tell you "I have a problem in this module", that means that I know for sure the problem is exactly there, I've identified it already and I need advice on fixing it. But if I tell you "I have a problem when using this module in conjunction with this theme" then the problem could be in either or even neither of them.

Comment: @MihaiStancu yes thank you so much for the breakdown.  It took me a while to ask the question in itself.  It's a theme I am using and you are correct I believe about the widget area being told to do something different then what it's originally programmed for.  I just don't understand why I cannot just tell the mobile side to respond properly (ie; cutting off).  With some luck I was hoping for a solution here.  I am trying to help a friend that is trying to get her site launched.  I also wished I had more knowledge in this area.  I am still praying for help.

Comment: @MihaiStancu I appreciate you for taking the time to explain some things to me as I am new to S.O. and will be helpful when I am thinking of asking another question.

Comment: I'll try and find a source for your problem. These theme=>module CSS conflicts are hard to identify at any level of experience. The theme has some very plausible CSS settings which the module indirectly inherits (making it break). Debugging this means you need to review every inherited property (which could affect width, overflow, positions etc.) that comes from theme files and applies to module objects.

Comment: @MihaiStancu I totally understand where u are coming from.   I have tried everything in my power.  And it all doesn't add up.  Thank you again for your help in looking into this.  Do you need any files from me?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read about responsive web design. That the layout of the site, and its section like widget/sidebar will adjust depending on the device size.

Comment: I have run in circles trying all that I can think it could be.  I need another pair of eyes to look at what I am not seeing.

Answer (score 0):

### Theory:

When responsive CSS kicks in for mobile view, some settings (which initially would have been set in pixels) are reset as percent values.

If you have an object which sets up a 10px left margin, 100% width and overflow: none. Anything within this object will be restricted to a width of 100%-10px.

If you have a child object (inside the initial object) with a width of 100%, the child object will appear to be positioned 10px to the right and 10px of its width will be chopped off.

### Problem identification:

I've found out where the boxes are set to cut-off:

```
// file: idx-broker-platinum.css
// line: 31
.home .IDX-showcaseWrapper,
.home .IDX-showcaseTable
{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100% !important;
    font-size: 16px !important;
}
```

This is not "the source" of the problem, it's a reasonable setting so long as other settings lower down would compensate.

Making sure the internal boxes are sized proportionally to this wrapper (when in mobile view) an that images are also sized proportionally to this wrapper will probably fix the issue.

### Solution:

Applying the following settings:

```
// <style> tag created by the plugin
// comment out the min-width;
#IDX-showcaseGallery-42182 .IDX-showcaseCell
{
    //min-width: 374px;
    width: 374px;
    max-width: 374px;
    padding: 0px;
}

// file: idx-broker-platinum.css
// line: 114
// replace the 100% width with another value such as 80%
.home .IDX-showcaseTable .IDX-showcaseCell,
.home .IDX-showcaseWrapper .IDX-showcaseDetails
{
    float: none;
    display: block !important;
    //width: 100% !important;
    width: 80% !important;
}
```

Will solve most of your problem -- the image/text appears to occupy the correct amount of space, it just doesn't respect the right-hand side white borders/paddings.

Comment: I added your lines of code and it didn't move anything on the mobile side.  All still looks the same.  The mobile is still cut off.

Comment: Apparently it wasn't the only change I had made while debugging :-). I've updated the answer to mention both changes I had made.

Comment: Unfortunately this second change targets some CSS which is added as a `<style>` tag (probably by the widgets' html theme) so changing it will be trickier.

Comment: Grrrrr this has been so frustrating.  I cannot make the widget in mobile view move over to the left to avoid being cut off.